Simulating effect of DD with AerSimulator
I am trying to simulate some simple dynamical decoupling sequences on AerSimulator with custom noise. Right now, I have  for the qc with DD, and $R_Y$ removed for the qc without DD
Then I implemented the noise model only on the 'id' gate with noise_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error, ['id']) and have tried different error types like
depolarizing error, thermal relaxation, amplitude damping and phase damping error
However, when I do the simulation with AerSimulator().run(qc, shots=8000, noise_model=noise_model).result() with the qc with and without DD, I saw no difference in .get_counts and the two circuit showed identical result (for all the noise models).
Is there any reason why this implementation would not work? Is it due to me not using the correct noise for DD to work?
edit:
Here is my code
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
from qiskit_aer import noise
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator

qc_no_dd = QuantumCircuit(1, 1)
qc_no_dd.rx(np.pi/2, 0)
qc_no_dd.barrier()
for i in range(6):
    qc_no_dd.id(0)
    qc_no_dd.id(0)
qc_no_dd.barrier()
qc_no_dd.rx(np.pi/2, 0)
qc_no_dd.measure(0, 0)

qc_dd = QuantumCircuit(1,1)
qc_dd.rx(np.pi/2, 0)
qc_dd.barrier()
for i in range(6):
    qc_dd.id(0)
    qc_dd.ry(-np.pi,0)
    qc_dd.id(0)
qc_dd.barrier()
qc_dd.rx(np.pi/2, 0)

qc_dd.measure(0, 0)

error = noise.depolarizing_error(0.03, 1)

noise_model = noise.NoiseModel()
noise_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error, ['id'])
simulator_aer = AerSimulator()

result_no_dd = simulator_aer.run(qc_no_dd, shots=8000, noise_model=noise_model).result()
result_dd = AerSimulator().run(qc_dd, shots=8000, noise_model=noise_model).result()

counts_no_dd = result_no_dd.get_counts()
counts_dd = result_dd.get_counts()

plot_histogram([counts_no_dd, counts_dd], legend=["no dd", "dd"], color=["red", "blue"])

I got ~1200 "0" and 6800 "1" for histogram result

Please share code and results.

Appended my code and result
